# SetWindowsHookEx for current thread returns null

Tags: windows, winapi

I have an issue trying to get a keyboard hook for the current thread.
Firstly, I needed to get keyboard input for all threads, so I used :

```
hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, mKeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
```

This works fine, but when I try to set the dwThreadId parameter (the last one) to GetCurrentThreadId(), SetWindowsHookEx returns NULL.

What could be the problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: *The hMod parameter must be set to NULL if the dwThreadId parameter specifies a thread created by the current process and if the hook procedure is within the code associated with the current process.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried with the hMod to NULL and still got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WH_KEYBOARD_LL` is a global hook, as stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx). That means that you must pass `0` for the thread ID parameter.

You could have diagnosed this yourself had you called `GetLastError`, as described by the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx). This would have returned error code `ERROR_GLOBAL_ONLY_HOOK`, *This hook procedure can only be set globally.*